# Correct way to run multithreading in a loop

Tags: php, multithreading

I am running an online shop, and I have a big file with email addresses of  customers, but the list is very old, like +15 years old. I bought code from codecanyon that checks the list, but it is very slow.

I tried to make it run multithreaded, but something is very wrong with my code, can you help me out?

The code works, but not the way I want it to. Now it checks the same email x %thread_nr. If I set 10 threads, it checks the same email  10x times.

What is wrong ?

```
<?php
require_once('email_checker.class.php');

class Task extends Threaded
{
    private $value;

    public function __construct(int $i)
    {
        $this->value = $i;
    }
    public function run()
    {
        $file_lines = file('mail.txt');
        $emailChecker = new emailChecker; // Make a new instance

        foreach ($file_lines as $line) {

            $response = $emailChecker->check($line);
            foreach($response as $result) {
                echo $result['query'].'-'.$result['success']."\n";
            }
        }


    }
}
$file_lines = file('mail.txt');
# Create a pool of 4 threads
$pool = new Pool(4);
for ($i = 0; $i < 15000; ++$i)
{
    $pool->submit(new Task($i));
}

while ($pool->collect());

$pool->shutdown();
```

Comment: Hi, I might be able to help. Can you explain better

Answer (score 0):

If I was in that situation I would rework the code so its cleaner, and broken into the smallest functions. Checking that the functions work individually.

I would also test that the code works without multi-threading first, with a small portion of your emails.

Comment: Great recommendations, but really just a comment, not an answer.

Comment: It seems like a comment, but actually it's the procedure for discovering where the error lies: http://www.mdcegypt.com/pages/management%20approaches/Lean%20enterprise/Types%20of%20Waste/Types%201.jpg